# Retain column in PivotTable even where it has no values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a column that shows debit or credit and next to it a column with the amounts. The PivotTable separates the debits and credits and lists the amounts in two different columns and works perfectly. But when there is no credit entry the credit column is not shown in the PivotTable. I need that column to stay there even if there is no value for credits.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have Show items with no data checked, in Layout & Print within Field Settings.